# SwiftUI Grouped List Causes Erratic Navigation

Tags: ios, ipad, navigation, swiftui, multitasking

The design for an app I'm working on calls for a multi-level master view and a single detail view. Each of these uses a grouped `List`. The following demonstrates the problem:

```swift
struct Content: View {
    let items = ["A", "B"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(item)) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                    .isDetailLink(false)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

            Text("Empty detail")
        }
    }
}
```

To reliably replicate the issue:

1. Enable multi-window support
2. Drag in a second copy of the app to enable multitasking
3. Drag the multitasking bar to eliminate the second copy of the app so there's only one window
4. Tap on an item in the master `List`

Here's the result on my iPad Pro (same result when testing in iPad simulator):

[image: SwiftUI Navigation Bug?]

Changing the `listStyle` to `DefaultListStyle` instead of `GroupedListStyle` fixes the issue, but this would require redesigning the app to accommodate the bug. May be related to an issue raised by @kontiki regarding the [back button](https://swiftui-lab.com/bug-navigationlink-isactive/), but I see no workaround. Suggestions?